# C++17 resumable/await : Can it also be used with boost::future?

Tags: c++, boost, c++17

In C++17, there's a nice future like C#'s `await`.

```
std::future<int> get_answer()
{
    return std::async(std::launch::async, [] { return 42; });
}
std::future<void> do_something() resumable
{
    // ...
    int a = await get_answer();
    // ...
}
```

But I wonder whether `boost::future` is also can used or not:

```
boost::future<int> get_answer()
{
    return boost::async(boost::launch::async, [] { return 42; });
}
boost::future<void> do_something() resumable
{
    // ...
    int a = await get_answer();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is in C++14.

Comment: There is no await or async in C++14.

Comment: What? http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3722.pdf is not C++14?

Comment: @ikh This feature has been deemed post-C++14 material and is being discussed for C++17 or for the Concurrency TS.

Comment: You can't really say "In C++17" about anything, as there isn't a  draft that can be called "C++17". The latest draft is C++14, and there is no newer draft with any additional classes in it ... so nothing is "in C++17" except what's already in C++14

Comment: @JonathanWakely However, when the guys in charge of _producing_ C++XX have said that it's not going to be in C++14, and will probably be in C++17, it makes sense to say "is being discussed for C++17"

Comment: @MooingDuck, that paper isn't even in the concurrency TS yet, and the stuff in there is not of standardisation quality. It's too early to say "X will probably be in C++17" for these proposals.

Comment: oh, I see. thanks for all your explanation.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about speculation. It belongs on the [std-proposals](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!forum/std-proposals) forum.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Are proposal-related questions off-topic? Why?

Comment: They have limited usefulness on Stack Overflow. See also Jonathan's comment above. It's a question about some temporary, shifting target that may or may not actually materialise itself.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Ummm.. I'm getting consfused about the criteria of off-topic :(

Comment: Oh. Don't get too bummed by the "off-topic" bit :S That's part of the semi-automated message the system generates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The paper that you linked ([N3722](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3722.pdf)) explicitly says that only `std::future<T>` and `std::shared_future<T>` are accepted as a return type for a `resumable` function:

> The return type of a resumable function must be future or shared_future
>   . The restrictions on T are
>   defined by std::future, not this proposal, but T must be a copyable or movable type, or ‘void.’ It must also be
>   possible to construct a variable of T without an argument; that is, it has to have an accessible (implicit or
>   explic
>   it) default constructor if it is of a class type.

However, the section 4 of the proposal (`Generalization`) proposes to lift the return type restriction. The returned type should be any type with the following restrictions:

> The operand of the unary operator `await` can be any type `S<<T>>` (“S eventually holding a T”) with meets the following conditions:
>
> 1. S has a parameter-less function `get` which will either eventually produce a value of type T, or throw an exception.
> 2. S has a function `then` accepting a single-parameter function object taking a parameter `S<<T>>`, `S<<T>>&`, or `const S<<T>>`. Once passed to `then`, the value held by the parameter must be immediately available for retrieval by a call to `get`.
> 3. Optionally, if `S<<T>>` has a `bool`-returning function `is_ready()` indicating whether a value is already held, the implementation of `await` can be made more efficient.

Currently, the discussion is still open. It the generalization is accepted, a `resumable` function will be able to return a `boost::future`. Otherwise, it will be limited to `std::future` and `std::shared_future`.

Comment: This answer is obsolete. http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4649.pdf